# Trying to use && in a css data-bind in Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am new to knockout and am trying to check two booleans.  Currently, I have:

```
data-bind="css: { hidden: bool1() }"
```

Hidden is a class I created in CSS.  I need to check against two bools to use the class or not.  It works fine with one bool.  How do I use two?

I tried the following:

```
data-bind="css: { hidden: bool1() && bool2() }"

data-bind="css: { hidden: bool1() + bool2() }"
```

I'm just not getting it.  Can anyone help please?

Comment: If they are observables, to use them in an expression, you have to call them: `bool1() && bool2()`.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work

Comment: Please post how and where `bool1` and `bool2` are defined.

Comment: I second Roy's comment. It catches me out often, you need to call the observables otherwise I think they are treated as objects and always evaluate to true.

Comment: Are you sure you are referencing the variables properly? Try using a tool like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof?hl=en to see if you are actually passing them in or calling them correctly.
Does it work with just one variable instead of both?

Comment: Yea, this seems to work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/nwjLnaom/

Comment: Thanks @RoyJ and ArrayKnight, the solution did work.  My use of false and true was off.  I don't know how to check your responses as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example. The text is hidden if both boxes are checked. You need to call the observables when using them in an expression in the binding.

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  bool1: ko.observable(),
  bool2: ko.observable()
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility:hidden;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="css:{hidden:bool1()&&bool2()}">I'm here!</div>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:bool1" />
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:bool2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
Oh! Silly me. Be sure to put in the parentheses after the bool1 and bool2.. so:

### `data-bind="css: {hidden: bool1(),  hidden: bool2()}"`

Also, be sure to put it in like a div tag, or whatever floats your boat.

There's a lot of documentation on http://knockoutjs.com/, so you should check that out of you haven't already. Tell me if it works.

Comment: That did not work (sad face).  I searched the docs and could not find && or its equivalent.  I also googled it and found nothing.

Comment: @VictorHu I think this will only hide the div when bool2() is true, not when both are true.

Answer (score 0):

This is another option (an extension to Roy J's), it keeps your html a little simpler, and makes refactoring easier **if** you use the combination of bools in more than one place.

```js
bool1 = ko.observable();
bool2 = ko.observable();

ko.applyBindings({
  bool1: bool1,
  bool2: bool2,
  shouldHideDiv: ko.computed(function () {
    return bool1() && bool2();
  })
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility:hidden;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="css:{hidden: shouldHideDiv}">I'm here!</div>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:bool1" />
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:bool2" />
```